# Inmersion of homogeneous straight cone into a liquid

Tags: buoyancy, fluid-statics, volume

I have a problem with an exercise that I require help:

Find the immersion of a homogeneous straight cone of height h and specific weight $\gamma_1$ in a liquid with specific weight $\gamma$.

The figure of the problem is this one [image: Figure of problem]

According the problem, the answer should be:

$$y=h \cdot \bigg[1-\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{\gamma_1}{\gamma}}\bigg] $$

The reason for this post is that I do not understand how to get the answer and what analysis  I should do with specific weights and heights, I would like any guidance about this problem.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are you familiar with Archimedes law (i.e. buoyant focres)?

Comment: Hi, yes, but basically, I saw this exercise and I tried to apply  Archimedes' law, buoyant forces but I was confused with specific weights and how to get the answer.

Comment: Please update the question to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi again Mr. Bernhard, I think I could solve it if you want you to check it out below. Thanks for being interested.

Answer (score 1):

After studying concepts about this problem, I think I could solve it through this procedure:
Following these previous concepts:

Density: $\rho$=$\frac{m}{V}$, m=mass and V=volume

Weight: w=mg, g=gravity acceleration

Specific weight: $\gamma$=$\frac{w}{V}$=$\frac{mg}{V}$=$\rho$g

According the situation, there must be a balance between immersed part by liquid and weight of the cone.

Wcone=mg=$\gamma_1$Vcone

Buoyancy Immersed part: E=$\gamma$Vpart

Then, $$Wcone=E$$ $$\gamma_1Vcone=\gamma Vpart$$
But the implicated volumes of the cone and the immersed part are these ones:
$$Vcone=\frac{\pi R^2h}{3}$$ $$Vpart=\frac{\pi y}{3} (R^2+r^2+Rr)$$ The immersed part is a cone trunk with height h=y.

Based on these volumes, the balance of forces can be rewritten
$$\gamma_1\frac{\pi R^2h}{3}=\gamma\frac{\pi y}{3} (R^2+r^2+Rr)$$

After grouping and deleting terms...
$$\frac{\gamma_1 R^2 h}{\gamma}=y(R^2+r^2+Rr)$$
$$\frac{\gamma_1 h}{\gamma}=y(1+\frac{r^2}{R^2}+\frac{r}{R})$$

Checking the picture again, I could realize there is a similarity of triangles.
[image]

$$\frac{h}{R}=\frac{h-y}{r}$$ It means...$$\frac{r}{R}=\frac{h-y}{h}$$
Then, the equation can be rewritten...
$$\frac{\gamma_1 h}{\gamma}=y(1+\frac{(h-y)^2}{h^2}+\frac{h-y}{h})$$
The common denominator is $h^2$, then...
$$\frac{\gamma_1 h}{\gamma}=y(\frac{h^2+(h-y)^2+h(h-y)}{h^2})$$
Grouping and executing terms...
$$\frac{\gamma_1 h^3}{\gamma}=y(h^2+(h-y)^2+h(h-y))$$
$$\frac{\gamma_1 h^3}{\gamma}=y(h^2+h^2-2hy+y^2+h^2-hy)$$
$$\frac{\gamma_1 h^3}{\gamma}=y(3h^2-3hy+y^2)$$
$$\frac{\gamma_1 h^3}{\gamma}=3h^2 y-3hy^2+y^3$$
Adding -$h^3$ to two sides of the equation...
$$\frac{\gamma_1 h^3}{\gamma}-h^3=3h^2 y-3hy^2+y^3-h^3$$
Multiplying -1 to two sides of the equation...
$$h^3-\frac{\gamma_1 h^3}{\gamma}=h^3-3h^2 y+3hy^2-y^3$$
Factorizing...
$$h^3(1-\frac{\gamma_1}{\gamma})=(h-y)^3$$
Cube root...
$$h-y=h \sqrt[3]{1-\frac{\gamma_1}{\gamma}}$$
Finding y...
$$y=h-h \sqrt[3]{1-\frac{\gamma_1}{\gamma}}$$
Finally, the height of the immersed part is
$$y=h[1-\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{\gamma_1}{\gamma}}]$$

Thanks for your attention.